# Backup software Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-11.10

I would like to know which backup software to use with my ubuntu server 11.10.
Currently my server uses raid 1 in order to don't have data loss, but I would like to have a restore iso because I'm starting to do some configuration that could ruin my current installation.

I tried Clonezilla with nodmraid option activated but after language selection it loops on usb devices found and disconnect without any possibility to go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an iso look at remastersys - this will create a full iso with all your files.

Shouldn't this be in ask ubuntu or unix/linux not stackexchange?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm sorry if this isn't the right place where to ask but I'm new on linux and I don't really know where to ask.

Comment: Try looking at the Superuser, AskUbuntu or Unix/Linux Q&A - find them on stackexchange. Stackoverflow is more for questions directly related to programming.